# Guava CharMatcher - extending ASCII definition

Tags: java, ascii, guava

I'm looking at some legacy code that read like:

```
CharMatcher.ASCII.retainFrom(content)
```

As such, Spanish special characters are filtered out. I need to update this logic,, so that Spanish chars are also included. Is anyone aware of a Guava / CharMatcher solution for this?

I can see I could use something like:

```
CharMatcher.inRange('\0', '\u017f');
```

, but Spanish chars are dispersed (randomly?) through the char set (and thus an "inRange" solution would pull in other, non Spanish chars that are greater than 127).

Thanks!
Damien

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own `CharMatcher` pretty easily with something like:

```
private static final CharMatcher MATCHER = CharMatcher.ASCII.or(
    CharMatcher.anyOf(<string containing other characters you want to match>));
```

Comment: He will probably need a string of `inRange`s combined with `or`s.

Answer (score 2):

If there's a simple way to test if a character is a special Spanish character, you can just do

```
CharMatcher.ASCII.or(new CharMatcher() {
  @OVerride public boolean matches(char c) {
    return // character is Spanish, however you want to check that
  }
});
```